# Get value of data attribut in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page i've got this :

```
<input type="hidden" class="fieldBasicData" data-name="adminvtech_tks_devis" data-type="string" data-displayvalue="181" data-value="181">
```

With Jquery I need to get the data-value (181 in this case) by searching by data-name (adminvtech_tks_devis in this case) in my HTML page.

How can I do that ?

I've tried this without success :

> alert( $('*[data-name="adminvtech_tks_devis"]' ).data("data-value") );

But i'm getting undefined in my alert box instead of 181.

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to omit the *data-* part in the key name:

`alert( $('*[data-name="adminvtech_tks_devis"]' ).data("value") );`

```js
alert( $('*[data-name="adminvtech_tks_devis"]' ).data("value") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" class="fieldBasicData" data-name="adminvtech_tks_devis" data-type="string" data-displayvalue="181" data-value="181">
```

Check out the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/934hzg82/)

Comment: While you answer is correct, please consider using the Stack Overflow snippet tool `<>`, that way the code is always avalible

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen cheers, wasn't aware